# How can I hide/show a link on a product page in woocommerce depending on its product category?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to show/hide a link dependent upon the product category in woocommerce. Basically, if the product is in the "Auction" category, I want a link to display that will take the viewer to the item on the auction website. I really didn't know where to start, but I have done this before to change css on scroll, so I was going to try and take the same approach (Changing the 'display' value dependent upon the product category. So far, this is what I was trying.

```
   <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
     if ($(product_cat) = "Auction") { // check if category is auction
      $("a.WireBids").css("display", "inherit"); // if yes, show wirebids link
    } else {
      $("a.WireBids").css("display", "none"); // if not, hide wirebids link
    }
  });
});
```

'

Comment: in Wordpress you need to use `jQuery(document).ready(function($){` instead to make it work…

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. However, I think I'm also using the wrong variable for product categories in woocommerce.

Comment: Why use Javascript for this? How does the javascript now what the product category is?

Comment: My thought process was to change the css dependent upon if the product_cat = "Auction" . What would you recommend? Essentially we post a lot of our items for auction. So Ideally instead of manually adding a link to the auction page for each item when the auction goes live, I could just add the category "Auction" and it would automatically make the link visible using 'display' to any items in that category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where you are trying to add this link, but `has_term()` seems like the right condition to apply here.

```
function so_43372512_maybe_show_auction_link(){

    if( has_term( 'auction', 'product_cat' ) ) {
        echo '<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com/">' . __ ( 'Auction Link', 'your-plugin' ) . '</a>';
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'so_43372512_maybe_show_auction_link', 35 );
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you definitely have a margarita coming from me. I'm not too experienced so I greatly appreciate the help! Worked Perfectly.